# Zabbix Media Type Script for sending SMS not working

Tags: bash, sh, zabbix

we wanted to implement our SMS gateway in Zabbix.

We got a cli tool (sms77-cli) for sending SMS which requires some parameters. However I did not found a way to do this directly with zabbix. Thats why I created a sh-script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
apikey="xxx"


/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts/sms77-cli --apikey $apikey --to $1 --text $2 --debug $3 >>/var/log/sms77.log
```

If I run the script from cli, it just works fine like this:

```
./callmeSMS.sh 001234567890 'bli bla blub' 1
```

Unfortunately the test in zabbix just runs into a timeout and I don't have a clue why. This is how I configured it in Zabbix:
[image: zabbix conf]

But the test result looks like this:
[image: zabbix error]

Zabbix is able to run the sh script, I tested it with a simple echo, but it seems that it doesn't call the sms77-cli tool... I'm running out of ideas. Can someone help?

Comment: Where did you put the script? What is the exit status when you run the script in shell? Please go to http://shellcheck.net check your script, fix mistakes and quote variable expansions and then try again

Comment: The script is at /usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts - if I run it on shell it just works and logs the output to the given path. No exit code. I fixed the quote variable expansions but still not working :(

Comment: `No exit code` No, every process exits with an exit code. Please do `./callmeSMS.sh 001234567890 'bli bla blub' 1 ; echo $?` in your terminla - what does `echo $?` output?

Comment: The output is 0.

Comment: Does anything show up in `/var/log/sms77.log` when you test the script from zabbix? Maybe add a `echo something > /var/log/sms77.log`? Also add `2>&1` on the end of line like `/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts/sms77-cli .... >>/var/log/sms77.log 2>&1`

Comment: I commented out the sms77-cli part and put an echo to it. This works just fine and appears in the logfile. The sms77-cli call seems not to work at all if run by zabbix itself. (nothing appears in the log file and exit code 255)

Comment: So `sms77-cli` exits with an error, and you have to find out why. So what user does the zabbix server run with? Maybe try `sudo -u zabbix-server ./callmeSMS.sh` and see if it works? Does that `sms77-cli` need any other configuration?did you add `2>&1`? Maybe try like `2>/var/log/sms77.error_logs`?

Comment: Zabbix server runs with "zabbix". Starting as this user works perfect on shell. Run via zabbix frontend, this appears in log: `Response:`.
I just changed the logging so that the cli tool itself logs with `--log` and it looks like its working but the cli tool is broken, because this appears in log: 
`2020-08-06.11:05:59 TO: 123, TEXT: Is it working or not?, FROM:
RESPONSE:
`

Comment: Run bash -x './callmeSMS.sh 001234567890 "bli bla blub" 1' to get debug output